# how to modify or check my $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, ros, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to install some development platform on Ubuntu 20.04. Here is what was said on the install-manual:

[check the screenshot here :D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0Z0D.png)

I'm not sure what to do now. It seems that I should modify the $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH by creating a "nrp_variable" in the .bashrc file. But I don't know the syntax, which could achieve it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is environment variable and you can just run `printenv CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to see content.

Also to solve issue try running command in green box.

Comment: This doesn’t answer OPs question.